# JNI_CreateJavaVM() fails every other time I run my application (exactly)

Tags: java, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, java-native-interface

I have a Windows MFC application that:

(1) Loads the JVM (`JNI_CreateJavaVM()`)

(2) Attaches the main thread to the JVM (`AttachCurrentThread()`)

(3) Loads some Java classes and methods (`FindClass()` and `GetMethodID()` / `GetStaticMethodID()`)

(4) Registers some native callbacks for use by Java code (`RegisterNatives()`)

(5) Detaches the thread from JVM (`DetachCurrentThread()`)

(6) Destroys the JVM (`DestroyJavaVM()`)

All of the above functions succeed *every other time* I run the application.  I know they succeed, because, additionally to the above, I interact with the application and successfully call Java static methods, and these Java methods successfully call my native callbacks.  My application exits gracefully, and it is certain that the expected Java functions, and native callbacks, have been executed.

However, *every other time* that I run the application, the call to `JNI_CreateJavaVM()` fails (not populating the `JavaVM *`).  **Absolutely nothing changes between runs of the application**.  I simply run it once (successfully, even *without* doing anything except the above 6 steps), quit gracefully, run again, and it fails, back and forth.  There are no exceptions to the back-and-forth success/failure - I can run it dozens of times, and it oscillates precisely every other time between success, and failing on the `JNI_CreateJavaVM()` line.

If necessary, I will paste more code.  However, I hope somebody has an insight with what I've provided.  (Note: this is a BCGSoft MFC property-sheet application, though I strongly doubt that matters.)

Comment: And by "every other time I run the application" you actually mean you start the entire process each time, right? Not just two method calls in a single process?

Comment: Correct.  In my case, I run in Debug mode and press F5 within Visual Studio to run the application.  Then, I exit the application completely.

Comment: I think at least edit and add the code that calls JNI_CreateJavaVM, especially how you populated the args.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are running into [this bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4712793) (restated [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6332506)) that is probably never going to be fixed.

Despite its name, `DestroyJavaVM()` does not actually destroy the JVM.  What it does is signal the JVM that it should shut down, but the JVM actually waits until all the threads other than the Main thread have stopped before it actually shuts down.  In fact, even then it does not fully clean up after itself, as [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html) states (quite [cryptically](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6701692)): "The JDK/JRE still does not support VM unloading, however."

Also, I'm concerned about your step 2, "Attaches the main thread to the JVM".  You do not need to attach the thread that created the JVM to the JVM and you may not detach that thread.  If you really are doing that, then it's possible that is what is messing up your system.  (The thread that creates the JVM is the JVM's "Main" thread.  You only need to attach/detach other native threads to the JVM if they need access to it.)

By the way, `JNI_CreateJavaVM()` returns 0 on success, and you say it returns 0 the "failed" times, so in what sense is it failing?  Which JVM (version, vendor) are you using?

Comment: Regarding the return value of 0 - actually, `JNI_CreateJavaVM()` does not return 0; thanks for pointing this out - it was a wrapper function within our application's code that returned NULL; I have removed that text from my question.  Regarding my Step 2 - I will look at that soon and post another comment.

Comment: In addition to the above comment, a question:  Do you think it's possible that the bug you have referenced might apply even in my case, in which the back-and-forth behavior was occurring between *runs* of the application - rather than within a single run?

Comment: @Dan, yes I think the bug can apply because you are running the program from within Visual Studio. If you read the comments on the bug you will see someone else had the same problem due to Visual Studio reusing the Debug thread.